# Insert two data into same column from two different textbox ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I try to insert two data into same column from two different text box. For example, one person that has two phone numbers. In this case the person and phone number are two separate table and phone number table is only have one column to store the phone number.
And I try to insert the data using stored procedure.
This is the stored procedure code.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Ph]
@name varchar(200),
@phonenumber varchar(200)

AS
Begin

Declare @P_ID int 

insert into person(Name)
values (@name)

SELECT P_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into phonenumber(PhoneNumber, P_ID)
values (@phonenumber, @P_ID)

RETURN
END
```

However, when I try to insert the data, an error message appear that quote "Procedure or function Ph has too many arguments specified.". This is the C# code for inserting the data.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YAMADA;Initial Catalog=testtest;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Ph", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox2.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3.Text;

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Does somebody can help me to fix this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are providing more arguments than needed.

Comment: If you need two phone numbers as input to the procedure, then define 2 procedure arguments for the numbers... `ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Ph] @name varchar (200), @phonenumber varchar(200), @phonenumber2 varchar(200)`

Comment: Then how to store it under same column? @user1429080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter you procedure to accept 2 phone numbers, then insert them one by one:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Ph]
    @name varchar(200),
    @phonenumber varchar(200),
    @phonenumber2 varchar(200)
AS
Begin

    Declare @P_ID int 

    insert into person(Name)
    values (@name)

    SELECT @P_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    insert into phonenumber(PhoneNumber, P_ID)
    values (@phonenumber, @P_ID)

    insert into phonenumber(PhoneNumber, P_ID)
    values (@phonenumber2, @P_ID)
END
```

Then add both phone numbers when you call the procedure:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YAMADA;Initial Catalog=testtest;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Ph", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedure accepts only two but you have added three, remove the last parameter. One more thing you have to note is that the second parameter should be of type varchar , but you were specified them as integer. Please change them as well. Finally the code will be

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Ph", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: How to store from another textbox to store another phone number with the same name?

Comment: You might want to consider adding a main table for the name and then a sub-table (a second table) that references back to the user (I would recommend giving each user a numerical value) and the you can have as many phone numbers as you like stored. It you only want two phone numbers, ever, then I would just have two fields in the main database. It's more about the database and table structure than the code in this case. ( @wudge solution for example puts both in one field) you then have to think about data and how it is extracted/displayed later as well. (Pen and paper time!)

Comment: How you are going to use the second phone number in the procedure? Anyway if you want to get another value to the stored procedure means you have to specify them first in the SP and then add that param in command

Answer (score 0):

First: You can only add each parameter once to the command.

As a solution you have three choices:

1. The clean approch with a second datatable in the DB.
   E.g.: userid, phoneid, phonenumber
   The userid ist the foreign key to your usertable. The phoneid is combined with the userid the primary key of your new table. And last but not least the phonenumber is one of the numbers of your User. Like this you can add as many phonenumber as you like to.
2. A dirty approch in my eyes: Change the column type of you phonenumber to nvarchar and add the phonenumbers as comma seperated values.
3. Add more phonenumber columns. EG. Phonenumber1, Phonenumber2... 
   But this approch is also not a desireable one as Theresa is still a problem when you want to add more numbers...

Last but not least: int is not a good choice as columntype.
What so you want to do with numbers like +49 177 77777777.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YAMADA;Initial Catalog=testtest;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Ph", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text;

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to store from another textbox to store another phone number with the same name?

Comment: Take a look into the procedure, `phonenumber varchar(200)`, which means that parameter should be varchar but you have specified them as integer. I have corrected them as well but still downvoted and you were gifted with a +1 for a wrong suggestion

Comment: I mean that I want to store two phone number into same column.

Comment: You're going to need a divider between those two phone numbers.  A space or something.  Otherwise you'll end up with 888-777-6666555-444-3333.  Also, if the database column has a limit to its value size (say, an American 10 digit number), what you are doing is impossible without a helper table to associate phone numbers to accounts (or changing the column, which is probably a bad idea).